# How to fix various RuntimeWarnings of type "overflow encountered in..." when using Least-squares minimization in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using the `least_squares()` function from the `scipy.optimize` module to calibrate a Canopy structural dynamic model (CSDM). The calibrated model is then used to predict leaf area index (lai) based on thermal time (tt) data.
I tried two variants, the first did not use the "loss" parameter of the least_squares() function, while the second set this parameter to produce a robust model.
The first model did not fit the data so well as the second.
However, with the second model I get this warnings:

```
res_robust = least_squares(fun, x0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(tt_train, lai_train))
__main__:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
__main__:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
C:\Anaconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py:220: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  z = (f / f_scale) ** 2
```

Nevertheless, the resulting fit from the second model (in green) looks well when plotted.
[image]

My dataset has too many characters after the decimal point which I don't actually need. Is it possible that the warnings has something to do with that? Can I ignore the warnings if this precision is not needed? Or the problem is more serious and the computations are compromised?

Here is my code. I apologize for hard codding a dataset that long.

```
# Canopy structural dinamic model (CSDM)

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tt_train = np.array([394.926, 629.43017, 681.39683, 921.36142, 979.08705, 1042.42455, 1109.76622, 1191.00372, 1348.94747, 1445.08913, 1631.68705, 1986.46622])
lai_train = np.array([0.35391, 0.77602, 0.78485, 1.11895, 3.12987, 3.21052, 4.85756, 5.1311, 6.22953, 7.33323, 7.38312, 3.86341])

# The CSDM formula (Duveiller et al. 2011. Retrieving wheat Green Area Index during the growing season...)
# LAI = k * (1 / ((1 + Exp(-a * (tt - T0 - Ta))) ^ c) - Exp(b * (tt - T0 - Tb)))

# initial estimates of parameters
To = 50      # plant emergence (x[0])
Ta = 1000    # midgrowth (x[1])
Tb = 2000    # end of cenescence (x[2])
k = 6        # scaling factor (arox. max LAI) (x[3])
a = 0.01     # rate of growth (x[4])
b = 0.01     # rate of senescence (x[5])
c = 1        # parameter allowing some plasticity to the shape of the curv (x[6])
x0 = np.array([To, Ta, Tb, k, a, b, c])

def model(x, tt):
    return x[3] * (1 / ((1 + np.exp(-x[4] * (tt - x[0] - x[1]))) ** x[6]) - np.exp(x[5] * (tt - x[0] - x[2])))

#Define the function computing residuals for least-squares minimization
def fun(x, tt, lai):
    return model(x, tt) - lai

# calibrate two models
# first is the simpler one - no error but poor fit    
res_lsq = least_squares(fun, x0, args=(tt_train, lai_train))
# then the robust model - gives overflow RuntimeWarning but the result seems well when plotted
res_robust = least_squares(fun, x0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=0.1, args=(tt_train, lai_train))

# termal time data for full season
tt_test = np.array([11.79375, 22.98125, 34.47708333, 45.46875, 56.95416667, 69.475, 84.39583333, 98.66875, 107.0416667, 116.7875, 129.7458333, 
141.04375, 152.9333333, 165.0791667, 180.425, 195.0395833, 209.71875, 224.3958333, 238.4020833, 252.1166667, 266.0625, 
281.0541667, 295.6270833, 310.4291667, 322.2916667, 331.6375, 338.11875, 346.7729167, 358.5770833, 369.5375, 380.3135, 
388.6364167, 394.926, 401.8093333, 409.1926667, 418.4239167, 425.3176667, 430.351, 436.0093333, 443.4780833, 451.61975,
460.3905833, 468.851, 475.3926667, 484.2051667, 497.26975, 506.9989167, 513.2426667, 519.7780833, 525.5176667, 531.9343333, 
539.2551667, 544.1426667, 549.8780833, 558.7655833, 565.49475, 568.7426667, 572.1030833, 575.55725, 578.0864167, 580.3155833,
583.0426667, 586.9280833, 592.651, 598.5155833, 602.5218333, 604.65725, 606.4968333, 610.776, 615.4135, 620.0718333, 627.8051667,
629.4301667, 629.776, 631.9176667, 635.83225, 643.8489167, 652.3989167, 662.1030833, 664.5718333, 666.3676667, 666.476, 
666.476, 666.476, 666.476, 667.5801667, 673.551, 681.3968333, 683.98225, 690.0614167, 697.301, 702.6093333, 704.9905833, 706.326,
710.39475, 713.3218333, 718.3093333, 721.90725, 724.0989167, 726.5364167, 729.7905833, 732.7635, 736.4780833, 739.0676667, 
742.4551667, 746.3114167, 746.5655833, 746.5655833, 746.5655833, 746.5655833, 746.5655833, 748.7864167, 751.9280833, 754.0614167,
754.0614167, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 754.6801667, 760.0489167, 766.0593333,
771.8551667, 775.7968333, 782.6843333, 795.9135, 801.8239167, 804.5530833, 807.4280833, 808.3218333, 811.5530833, 816.31975,
817.4114167, 818.1405833, 820.3364167, 823.2301667, 825.2468333, 827.9676667, 831.8093333, 835.48225, 838.2280833, 840.1135,
840.8405833, 842.8385, 843.66975, 844.0385, 844.9551667, 844.9551667, 844.9551667, 844.9551667, 844.9551667, 844.9551667,
844.9551667, 845.8093333, 845.8093333, 845.8093333, 846.6739167, 849.451, 852.89475, 860.151, 867.6780833, 878.5593333,
889.301, 900.2155833, 911.3155833, 921.3614167, 931.2989167, 944.3405833, 947.4405833, 947.4405833, 947.4405833, 948.4426667,
948.4426667, 948.4426667, 948.4426667, 948.6078841, 949.8453841, 954.3495507, 960.8703841, 967.9453841, 979.0870507, 996.1058007,
1009.132884, 1019.322467, 1029.478717, 1042.424551, 1057.395384, 1069.930801, 1082.962051, 1095.920384, 1109.766217, 1124.191217,
1140.557884, 1156.843301, 1173.526634, 1191.003717, 1206.739134, 1221.112051, 1233.226634, 1247.184967, 1263.372467, 1278.449551,
1293.843301, 1311.147467, 1329.207884, 1348.947467, 1368.468301, 1388.553717, 1407.682884, 1426.270384, 1445.089134, 1461.795384,
1481.364134, 1499.868301, 1518.032884, 1538.305801, 1559.057884, 1578.743301, 1596.380801, 1614.578717, 1631.687051, 1648.178717,
1665.380801, 1682.168301, 1699.143301, 1713.870384, 1731.584967, 1749.303717, 1766.366217, 1784.191217, 1801.568301, 1818.239134,
1835.541217, 1853.730801, 1872.880801, 1891.470384, 1910.580801, 1929.641217, 1948.868301, 1967.932884, 1986.466217, 2005.532884,
2024.989134])

# apply the two models on the full season data    
lai_lsq = model(res_lsq.x, tt_test)
lai_robust = model(res_robust.x, tt_test)

plt.plot(tt_train, lai_train, 'o', markersize=4, label='training data')
plt.plot(tt_test, lai_lsq, label='fitted lsq model')
plt.plot(tt_test, lai_robust, label='fitted robust model')
plt.xlabel("tt")
plt.ylabel("LAI")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `f_scale`?

Comment: @Patol75, I get the value of 0.1 for `f_scale` from an example script I found in Internet and kept it unchanged as I was not sure of its meaning. Now I tried increasing the value by 0.1 in steps and see what will happen. Up to 0.7 the same warnings appeared, but when setting the parameter to 0.8 or higher (I stopped at 1.5) there were no warnings. However, increasing the value made the two model fits more and more alike, and at 1.5 the two lines in the plot coincided almost perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According to the above, setting a small value for `f_scale` (represented as C in the formula) increases the value of the argument given to `rho`. This potentially generates the Overflow. Increasing the value of `f_scale` helps deal with the warning, however it gives a less satisfying fit. Perhaps using a different loss function, such as `cauchy` could help.

Comment: I tested the same script with another data set and get the same warnings even with the standard method (i.e. without using `loss='soft_l1'`). It seems the problem is more serious.